# Is there an alternative way to create Junit Test results report instead of ant's Junitreport task

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, junit, junit4

We are using Ant's Junitreport to create result of runing Junit. The code is like this:

```
<target name="report.html">
    <junitreport todir="${test.reports}">
        <fileset dir="${test.reports}">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml" />
        </fileset>
        <report todir="${test.reports}" />
    </junitreport>
</target>
```

The problem is that it is not working properly with Java. The first time when we upgraded Java to Java 7 it stopped working! Now I upgraded Java to Java 1.7.05 and changed it to 64 bits version instead of 32. It stopped working again. I ma getting a transformation error like this:  Errors while applying transformations: Fatal error during transformation

Two question:

1. Is there an alternate method instead of Junitreport?
2. If not what the error is depend on?

Comment: so this is your build.xml, do you have a build.properties and build-local.properties these need to have the jdk.version and jdk.home updated when a new version is added.

Comment: Actually we didn't have a build.properties or build-local! But I can test it do you know how can I write jdk version in build.properties?

Comment: should be like this:
jdk.version=1.7
jdk.home=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_05 or whatever versions you are using

Comment: We are using eclipse to run ant. I think eclipse is declaring this configuration in its launcher configuration! Is it not som?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a problem with ant 1.8.2 and lower. It seems to be the same bug(s) that caused these problems:

[<junitreport> broken on JDK 7 when a SecurityManager is set](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51668)

[<xslt> with redirect broken on JDK 7 when a SecurityManager is set](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=52382)

There seems to be a problem with using ant from within Eclipse and NetBeans.

[<junitreport> broken inside IDE on JDK 7](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=201022)

[Ant build fails in junitreport using Java 6u32 or later](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=384757)

Try using a newer version of ant, such as 1.8.3 or even better 1.8.4.

Comment: Yes we had that problem than we downloaded the ant 1.8.3 and it works! Then I installed the eclipse Juno which has ant 1.8.3 as default and it worked with Java 1.7.02. But then I updated java to 1.7.05 64 bits (eclipse is 64 bits too) and it stopped working again! I wonder if ant 1.8.3 is not working with java 1.7.05 or it deponds on 64 bits version!

Answer (score 0):

It is not really related to Java version.  Did your tests fail when you switched to new platform?

The ant task uses xslt processing on xml. If it has some very large strings in error, it may give the error some what like what you wrote.

Comment: No, tests are working as they should! I think the problem because the versions of java are using different XML transformer engine!

Answer (score 0):

change the versions of java and Ant..
check http://www.duncanjauncey.com/blog/archives/41